# JSHint - Unreachable 'break' after 'return'

Tags: javascript, jshint

So I have been developing a modal control for several months. It is custom coded to my clients needs but I want to release it to the generic public. I have been working to get it to minify via codekit as well as uglify.

Here is an example of the remaining warnings I am receiving.

How can I best remove theses warnings? I extended the typeof function in order to know the variations between objects and arrays.

```js
var com = {
 load: function(template, $el, obj, append, callback){
  $.get(template, function(value){
   $.templates("tmpl", value);
   var html = $.render.tmpl(obj);
   if(append){ $el.append(html); }else{ $el.html(html); }
  }).done(function(){
   if(callback !== undefined && com.type(callback) === "function"){ callback(); }
  });
 },
 checkApiEvents: function(api){
  if(!$.isEmptyObject(api.doc)){ $.each(api.doc, function(k,v){ if(com.type(v) === "function"){ $.e.doc[k].push(v); } }); }
  if(!$.isEmptyObject(api.win)){ $.each(api.win, function(k,v){ if(com.type(v) === "function"){ $.e.win[k].push(v); } }); }
 },
 type: function(name){
  switch(name){
   case "function": return "function"; break;
   case "object": if($.isArray(name)){return "array"; }else{ return "object"; } break;
   case "string": return "string"; break;
   case "number": if(!isNaN(name)){ return "number"; }else{ return "string"; } break;
   case '': case "undefined": default: return "undefined"; break;
  }
 },
};
```

[image]

Comment: Don't break after you return. Nothing executes after a return. A return is enough, the break is unreachable and unnecessary. Get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, after adding a break brefore the default it cleared all the remaining warnings,

Comment: If it's actually about making the warnings not show up (i.e. you're temporarily using an early return to test something), you can specify `/* jshint -W027 */`. Not recommended for production, of course

Answer (score 1):

If you find this question looking for the error in `jshint W027 - Unreachable '$' after 'return'` and want to return early (for now) then an easy solution to make the jshint warning go away is to use a conditional:

```
function doThis(){
    if (1) return true;
    // I want to keep this but return early for now
    myVar = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `break` to break off a loop or switch not going further down the body of 
 the block(loop/switch). The `return` breaks off from the function itself. So once a return is called there no point of any statement after a return.

Answer (score -1):

A `return` statement "exits" the function immediately so any code after it will never be run.

```
function hello() {
    console.log('this will run');
    return;
    console.log('this will never run');
}
```

Yes, you can put `return` statements inside `if` blocks, but if they're called, nothing after that `return` statement, or outside the `if` block will be run either.

```
function hello() {
    console.log('this will run');

    var x = true;

    if (x === true) {
        console.log('this will run');
        return;
        console.log('this will never run');
    }
    else {
        return; // this will never return
    }

    console.log('this will only run if x is false');
}
```